# Error in datetime when application is deployed

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a start date that must be valid, it must be taken place after the requestdate.
When I compare it in visual studio in the debug and the releasemode, it's fine. 
Now I deployed the application but the compare time comes back with:

> loadingdate 01-01-0001 is invalid

even if the date is set to the future like: 23-02-2015.

```
private Boolean IsStartDateValid(ShipmentPlanningTruck truck)
{
   int comparedDate = truck.Loadingdate.CompareTo(requestdate);

   if (comparedDate < 0)
      return false;
   return true;
 }
```

and the call is here:

```
if (!IsStartDateValid(truck))
     throw new Exception(String.Format("Loadingdate {0} is invalid", truck.Loadingdate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")));
```

I get the requestdate from the database and set it like:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dr["HRDTE"].ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out requestdate))
    header.Requestdate = requestdate;
 else
    header.Requestdate = default(DateTime);
```

The loadingdate is from the user and in the frontend formated to: `return expexteddate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");`

and before the validation is done the loadingdate is paresed to a datetime:

```
 DateTime loadingDate;
 if(DateTime.TryParse(dr["Loadingdate"].ToString(), out loadingDate))
        truck.Loadingdate = loadingDate;
 else
        truck.Loadingdate = default(DateTime);
```

Comment: How is the request date being set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the server has different regional and language settings so the date format si different. you need to set a format for your dates.

it works when the day is lower of equal to 12?

Comment: This is a pretty big leap considering there's nothing to do with strings on the code in the question.

Comment: Yes, the date and month are indeed wrong. But when I look at the inputed loadingdate its the default datetime.

Answer (score 1):

You should explicity convert string to DateTime with defined format. See below:

```
var startDateString = "23-02-2015";
var startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDateString, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then you can just compare two dates instead of ints.

Answer (score 0):

First Check where is your server. I am also handled the same issue. So i convert the timezone. Use the following syntax,

Create one common class for this and use all every places,

```
    public static DateTime CurrentTime()
    {


        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(dateTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "India Standard Time"); // here you can mention the timeZone exactly.
        return timeZone;
    }
```

Hope it should help.